# Angular 4 material toolbar color not changing

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli, angular-material2

I'm trying to setup Angular Material for an angular 4 project.

I followed the [how to get started guide](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started) and pretty much have everything except a few things

1. Toolbar component doesn't change colors when I add `color="primary"`
2. Font family for toolbar doesn't seem right, in fact, I think the css it's trying to fetch is not correct.
3. Font family for stuff that do not required custom material components are weird

I've setup a simple repository [here](https://github.com/johhansantana/angular4-material-help) using angular-cli 1.4.9

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the toolbar?

Answer (score 14):

Add below code in `style.css`

```
.mat-toolbar.mat-primary {
  background: #007bff;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: This is hard coding the style while skipping the theme itself.

Comment: you're discarding the purpose of angular material by doing so!

Answer (score 8):

On a simple app that exercises a library in a multi projects workspace, the toolbar remained not styled with a white background.

I could solve the issue by adding in the `styles.scss` file, the following import statement:

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css'
```

Comment: This is the correct answer to this problem, which fixed it for me. The top answer above doesn't really address the underlying issue of the primary style not working, it just bypasses it through hard coding.

Answer (score 3):

1. <del>There's nothing wrong with your code. Can you check in your DevTools that the `mat-primary` class is applied to your toolbar?</del>

   UPDATE: It looks like you're missing the module required for `mat-toolbar` to work. Add `MatToolbarModule` to your app's module:

   ```ts
   import {
       MatToolbarModule,
       // Other module imports
   } from '@angular/material';

   @NgModule({
       imports: [
           MatToolbarModule,
           // Other modules go here
       ]
   })
   ```
2. That's because you're missing the css for Roboto. Add the import CSS in your app's `index.html`:

   ```html
   <head>
       <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>
   ```
3. You should either add `mat-typography` style to your `body` element in `index.html`:

   ```html
   <body class="mat-typography">
       <app-root></app-root>
   </body>
   ```

   Alternatively, add the following style to your `styles.scss`:

   ```scss
   body {
       font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
   }
   ```

Comment: I tried each and every one of your points, on my simple app that exercises a library in a multi projects workspace, and still, the toolbar remained unstyled and white.

Comment: @Stephane Did you include the theming styles?

Comment: Yes, see my solution above.

Answer (score 2):

```
  <mat-toolbar color="primary">
  <button
    mat-icon-button
    class="cursor-pointer example-icon favorite-icon"
    aria-label="Example icon-button with heart icon"
    (click)="dataStorerService.sidenavOpen = !dataStorerService.sidenavOpen"
  >
    <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
  </button>

  <span>Dashboard</span>
  <span class="example-spacer"></span>
</mat-toolbar>
```

This is my code but the primary color was not getting reflected in the browser.
on importing the below in styles.scss file

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
```

changes started to reflect

*Reason for the issue faced:*
At times while installing Angular material to the project using the command

```
ng add @angular/material
```

> Choose a prebuilt theme name, or "custom" for a custom theme: (Use
> arrow keys)
>
> > Indigo/Pink        [ Preview: https://material.angular.io?theme=indigo-pink ]   Deep Purple/Amber  [
> > Preview: https://material.angular.io?theme=deeppurple-amber ]
> > Pink/Blue Grey     [ Preview:
> > https://material.angular.io?theme=pink-bluegrey ]   Purple/Green
> > [ Preview: https://material.angular.io?theme=purple-green ]
> > Custom

incase if the installing of the theme doesn't happen properly, it might result in this issue as well!

Answer (score 1):

Verify that the theme CSS is added in `angular.json` under `projects/architect/build/options`:

```
"styles": [
  "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
  "src/styles.less"
],
```

And rerun `ng serve` after that.

Answer (score 0):

No need to add color="primary".

Simply override the color of mat-toolbar in CSS by:

```
.mat-toolbar {
   background: teal;
   color: #fff
}
```

To know which CSS class to override, inspect the element in browser and then seeing the underlying CSS classes.

Answer (score 0):

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
  <h1>My Application</h1>
</mat-toolbar>
```

this should work very fine, don't try to override material styles in any css file, you can of course if you want custom colors or something.
to check if everything alright, your project must first of all import angular material and then:

1. have this in your angular.json file :

   ```
       "styles": [
         "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
         "src/styles.css"
       ]
   ```

of course the style depends on the one ypou chose, for me I chose indigo-pink

2. import angular material in the component you want to use it inside

   imports: [
   MatToolbarModule
   ]

Answer (score -3):

I was able to find only these two:

`primary` should be defined and exported from the class in `app.component.ts`

and `app.component.scss` should be `app.component.css`.

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  primary = 'red';
}
```

and you need to tell angular that you want it to be populated by using `{{primary}}` in your `app.component.html` file.

Comment: `primary` is a correct attribute for the `@Input() color`. It doesn't have to be defined in `app.component.ts`.